# Why ftp_put is changing my files?

Tags: php, file, ftp

Today I'm trying to make FTP connection with PHP. I used `ftp_put` and it's working fine (with .txt file) until I wanted to upload a PHP file.

When I'm uploading a PHP file, all my tags `<?php  ?>` are removed... I don't know why and I found nothing about some FTP security in PHP...

Someone can help me ?

Comment: How are you testing to see that the tags have been removed? Are you viewing the uploaded files in a web browser?

Comment: I tested in a web browser but I have a 500 error. When I take my files with FileZilla I can see that all PHP tags are removed.

The 500 error is weird because the file contains only some html tags with a echo(); ...

Comment: Do a "view source" in your web browser when looking at the file with filezilla, and see if the php tags are visible then

Comment: I can't I have 404 error. But when I take the file on my computer to see the source, php tags aren't inside.

Comment: I think ASCII mode is default, can you try ftp_put() in binary mode? It will upload the file bit-by-bit instead of parsing for ASCII text. I hope your hosting company isn't doing something extra behind the scenes. http://php.net/manual/en/function.ftp-put.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem... It was the file path.. I forgot to remove http ... :')

Thanks you for your help.